# the need for article when the noun is further elaborated using who

Tags: articles, definite-article

I have the following phrase:

> ...could be the early detection of users who are likely to
>   under-participate in the activity, as well as users who are likely to
>   perform enough as required.

In this sentence, I wonder if I should better put `the` before each `users` or it is not necessary. As far as I know, there should be since the 'users' are further specified, but then it sounds a little redundant as well. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you can answer the question "which users?"

- If your answer is "doesn't matter" or "any possible group of users who are likely to under-participate in the activity", then no article is needed.
- If your answer is something like "a definite group of users, who are likely to under-participate in the activity, that I saw or was talking about before", use *the*.
- If your answer is something like "well, I saw multiple groups of users, who are likely to under-participate in the activity, and I'm talking about at least one but not all of them", use *some*.

*Who* qualifies "users" but doesn't really affect the choice of article.

Answer (score 2):

No "**the**" is required the way I see it.

- ...could be the early detection of **users** who are likely to under-participate in the activity, as well as **users** who are likely to perform enough as required.

You have two global categories of users that are unspecified.

See example:

- We are talking about **animals** that leave in the woods, as well as **animals** living in the forest?

Comment: Did you mean *"is not required"*?

Comment: @user178049 Yes, I wrote that! "**No "*the*" is required the way I see it.**"

Comment: Damn. My eyes add a comma, I see"No, 'the' is required"